# Define Data Integrity, specifically Intra Record Integrity when working with databases

Tags: sql, database, validation, integrity

I'm wondering if anyone can explain in simple enough terms what Intra-Record Integrity means when working with Databases? The definition i have is "enforcing constraints on contents of fields linked to data validation" but was hoping someone could elaborate further?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one explanation to this which depends heavily on the word "intra-record".

Let's start with an example, lets say you have a health record for a patient, it has fields such as

```
ID 
GENDER
AGE
DATE_OF_BIRTH
LAST_MENSTRUAL_DATE
```

Now if the value of GENDER is `Male`, then the LAST_MENSTRUAL_DATE is normally NULL or blank.

Similarly if you have populated both the fields AGE and DATE_OF_BIRTH, and lets say you have DATE_OF_BIRTH = `January 1 1976` and AGE = 30, this is incorrect since if a person is born on `January 1 1976` the AGE should be 40 or, if the AGE is in fact 30 then the DATE_OF_BIRTH should be `January 1 1986`.

NOTE: It would be bad design to include both AGE and DATE_OF_BIRTH columns in the same table, the above is just to show the case of data integrity

So this way fields within a record i.e. **intra-record** are valid and do not violate data integrity.

This is one explanation of what intra-record data integrity means, there might be others which are more formal and academic.

Depending on what database type you are using, there can be various ways of implementing such constraints on field values.